# Job stops in between without showing any error

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, density-of-states

I am trying to calculate the dos of one bulk system. My dos calculation job stops in between without showing any error. Here I am attaching the link of my input dos calculation files. CONTCAR file is also empty.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NLr_2ZCLqhGk3raoDykEfsikK7k1Ub6p?usp=sharing

Comment: Most likly it is segmentation error, running out of memory Your KPOINTS is not appropriate. Kindly change KPOINTS to 1 13 13. use IALGO=38

Comment: Does the @pranavkumar suggestions help?

Comment: yes, this problem is solved.

Comment: You could add your corrected input file, along with some explanation, as an answer.

Comment: @pranavkumar since your suggestion seems to have solved the problem, would you be willing to write an answer if we re-open this? Poonam, if Pranav says no, then can you write an answer explaining how the problem got solved?

Comment: @Tyberius it got answered! Thanks for re-opening it :)

Answer (score 3):

The most common problem in vasp for any job to stop is out of memory. Before going through debugging whole process, first check your structure in `VESTA/OVITO`, if you structure seems correct then run one SCF calculation with `ALGO=N` or `IALGO=38`, with `KPOINTS` to single gamma point. Once everything is fine, increase your kpoints.  For surface calculation vacuum of 10-15 Angstrom is enough and Kpoints to be 1.